# Scaling the WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, kinect

In kinect the co ordinates of the main window starts from the centre(view area) of it.
I want to scale this window to the specified size like 640*480.
I am using C# for this.
Thank you in advance.

Note : I don't want to use any libraries for this.

Comment: Please stop `> blockquoting` all your questions, it's annoying to read and doesn't help make your questions any better.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options:

- use ViewBox
- use a Layout-ScaleTransform
- use a Render-ScaleTransform

As I don't know exactly what you want I cannot advise you on what to use but if I get the hint with the "centre" right I would start by using the layout-scaletransform.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ScaleTransform and put it in the LayoutTransform of your Window.
You'll have to calculate the ScaleX & ScaleY based on your current X & Y-value because it works with percentages. Standard values for ScaleX & ScaleY will be 1 (= 100%)

If you want to know the difference between RenderTransform & LayoutTransform read [this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference/) article.